# trying to understand some codes related to window.onload in js

Tags: javascript

```
<body>  
<script language="javascript">
window.tdiff = []; fred = function(a,b){return a-b;};
window.onload = function(e){ 
    console.log("window.onload", e, Date.now() ,window.tdiff, 
    (window.tdiff[1] = Date.now()) && window.tdiff.reduce(fred) ); 
}
</script> 
</body>
```

Above code is taken from a site.

In firefox->console, it shows:

```
window.onload load 1372646227664 [undefined, 1372646227664] 1372646227664
```

Question:

1. For `window.tdiff->[undefined, 1372646227664]`, why not:`[]`, because when runs to code:`window.tdiff`, it is still an empty array?
2. For `window.tdiff.reduce(fred)->1372646227664`, `window.tdiff = [undefined, 1372646227664]`, `undefined - 1372646227664`, should be `NaN`, why it shows `1372646227664`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For window.tdiff->[undefined, 1372646227664], why not:[], because when
>   runs to code:window.tdiff, it is still an empty array?

It is not an empty array, when you say code:window.tdiff you refer to the point in which its passed to the method as an parameter, but by the time console.log function evaluates the value you passed in, its no longer an empty array, as it has been filled by the next parameter.

```
> (window.tdiff[1] = Date.now()) && window.tdiff.reduce(fred) )
```

As pointed out in other answer by Arun P Johny, reduce is not applying fred() on the undefined element, that's why you don't get an NaN

Answer (score 0):

1. Because array is a complex javascript type and its value passed by reference, so you have a [] in console, but for some milliseconds, after **window.tdiff[1] = Date.now()** your empty array is replaced by new value. If you will use window.tdiff.slice(), you will get an empty array in console (because slice create a new copy of array, with a new reference)
2. Reduce callback just not run with undefined (non-inited or not-initilized) value. In your case reduce just return the second value. To see how it works use MDN Reduce Compatibility section by this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

P.S. If you add console.log to fred you  will se that is doesn't call

Answer (score 0):

1. it fills in the second element of the `diff` array before calling `console.log`.
2. from the documentation: `reduce` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description) excludes holes in the array, and since your array have only one element, it is returning that as the result of reduce